# Is there a less hacky way to do this in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get the last inserted product by a user. This is what I've came up with

```
   $query = 'SELECT id
                 FROM products
                 WHERE user_id = ?
                ORDER BY id DESC
                       LIMIT 1';
```

It *should* work because the id is auto increment. To me though, it feels hacky. Is there a better way to do this?

I can't use `mysql_last_insert_id()` or anything like that because I need the last product by a specific user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT MAX(t.id) AS id
    FROM PRODUCTS t
   WHERE t.user_id = ?
```

[MAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) is an aggregate function, returning the maximum value of the column specified.  Because the query is only returning one column - the one the aggregate function is being used on - the `GROUP BY` clause doesn't need to be specified.  But there's no harm in using:

```
  SELECT MAX(t.id) AS id
    FROM PRODUCTS t
   WHERE t.user_id = ?
GROUP BY t.user_id
```

Comment: That *is* a bit better... I feel foolish for forgetting about these things in MySQL. Thanks!

Comment: This is a great solution, but you (alex) should really consider adding a 'created' field to your schema. It's a really valuable column to have if you make sure your models are filling it in properly. MySQL can do a lot of date comparison selection for you and it's a lot more surefire than the greatest record ID for something like this.

Comment: I agree, but it's Alex's data model & you should vote up Andy Wests answer if you agree with it.

Answer (score 5):

I would add a DATETIME column to your table for this purpose.  I personally don't feel comfortable relying on the behavior of AUTO_INCREMENT from the standpoint of ordering.  Besides, its purpose is to "generate a unique identity for new rows."  Aside from that, you shouldn't really care about the value.

Comment: That's a good idea... how would you write your query then to get the newest product?

Comment: Assuming your DATETIME column stored the time the product was added (using NOW(), for example), you could just replace the id in OMG Ponies' example with the date.

Comment: alex: just like your original but with ORDER BY datetime_column_name DESC, id DESC;

Comment: @ysth: I would say using an aggregate is normally preferred over selecting a larger set and using the LIMIT clause.

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM ...
```

Not sure how much better that would be, tho :)

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with Datetime Column option. 
for e.g. you have column named LastAddedDate Datetime
then you can make query like

> Select top(1) Products.Id from
>   Products where User_Id=@UserId order
>   by LastAddedDate,Id Desc

or else in case of id also you can write query

> Select top(1) Products.Id from
>   Products where User_Id=@UserId order
>   by Id Desc

Comment: The question specifies MySQL, where there is no SELECT TOP().  The alternative is LIMIT, which has already been discussed.